# Azure Hosted Agent Pipeline Expand Dynamic Environment Variable

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm having an issue expanding a dynamic variable within an Azure Pipeline using an Azure Powershell task. How can I get $whatever to resolve to https://whatever.com?

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=eus2-webAppName;]https://whatever.com";
[string[]] $regionsToSwap = "eus2".Split("|");

$regionsToSwap | ForEach-Object {
    $whatever = "$_-webappName";
    Write-Output $($whatever) # <-- Resolves to eus2-webAppName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
Write-Output (ls env:\$whatever | select-object -expandproperty value)
```

Comment: running that gives me the following exception

+     Write-Output (ls $env:\$whatever | select-object -ExpandProperty  ...
+                      ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using 
${} to delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

Comment: sorry, had a typo there

Comment: That still doesn't resolve to the pipeline variable. I now get the following error:

ls : Cannot find path 'eus2-webappName' because it does not exist

Comment: this means its not there, you can test it with `ls env:`